# Can we use both aws dynamodb version 1.x and 2.x in same project?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The reason I was asking this because aws sdk dynamodb version 2.x doesn't have support for DynamoDB Mappers. So I want to leverage dynamodb mapper from 1.x and automatic pagination and other features from 2.x.

Or Is there any alternative to dynamodb mappers in aws sdk 2.0?
Please let me know. thanks

Comment: Can someone please answer the original question? That can we use AWS services 1.x and 2.x in same project?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Java SDK for DynamoDB indeed supports DynamoDB Mappers:

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html

And the GitHub Source:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java

You can  use  DynamoDB Mapper as from the latest SDK as below:

```
package com.amazonaws.codesamples;

import java.util.Set;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBIgnore;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName="ProductCatalog")
public class CatalogItem {

    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String ISBN;
    private Set<String> bookAuthors;
    private String someProp;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="Id")  
    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Integer id) {this.id = id; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Title")  
    public String getTitle() {return title; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="ISBN")  
    public String getISBN() { return ISBN; }
    public void setISBN(String ISBN) { this.ISBN = ISBN; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="Authors")
    public Set<String> getBookAuthors() { return bookAuthors; }
    public void setBookAuthors(Set<String> bookAuthors) { this.bookAuthors = bookAuthors; }

    @DynamoDBIgnore
    public String getSomeProp() { return someProp; }
    public void setSomeProp(String someProp) { this.someProp = someProp; }
}
```

And later:

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();

DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

CatalogItem item = new CatalogItem();
item.setId(102);
item.setTitle("Book 102 Title");
item.setISBN("222-2222222222");
item.setBookAuthors(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("Author 1", "Author 2")));
item.setSomeProp("Test");

mapper.save(item);
```

Comment: But this mapper is 1.x.  this is not implemented in 2.x. So the question is can I use both versions?  Say if I have 2.x vetsion can  I use mappers?

Answer (score 0):

It actually has the Mapper within version 2.
https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/mapper/annotations/DynamoDbPartitionKey.html

It is in software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.